# Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

Tags: node.js, tedious

I am trying to get data from database but getting following error { message: 'Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state',
  code: 'EINVALIDSTATE' }. If I call only one query function then it's working but not for multiple

Below is my code

```
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
// If no error, then good to proceed.
if(!err)
{
    console.log("Connected");
    executeStatement();
    executeStatement2();
}
else
{
    console.log(err);
}
});

var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function executeStatement() {
request = new Request("Select p.product_name, s.product_id, s.price,   s.create_date, s.update_date from products p left join sale s on (p.id = s.product_id) order by CONVERT(datetime, s.update_date ) desc ;", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);}
});

request.on('row', function(columns) {
        var rowObject ={};
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
        });
        var jsonArray = [];
        jsonArray.push(rowObject);

});

connection.execSql(request);
}


function executeStatement2() {
request = new Request("Select * from products ;", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

request.on('row', function(columns) {
    var rowObject ={};
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
        rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
    });
    var jsonArray2 = [];
    jsonArray2.push(rowObject);

});
 connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: var connection = new Connection(config);config should contain valid username and password properties to connect to the database

Comment: Same error but a different issue, just in case someone like me ended up on this thread to look for this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608795/ransactionerror-requests-can-only-be-made-in-the-loggedin-state-not-the-final/72608796#72608796

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a same problem. You can't run two different query requests. The solution is using from one query request and

`request.on('requestCompleted', function () {
      // Next SQL statement.
  });`

It is mentioned in this issue:
https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/458

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution in https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/458.
I had the same issue and this solution resolve my issue

```
const {Connection, Request} = require("tedious");
const executeSQL = (sql, callback) => {
  let connection = new Connection({
    "authentication": {
      "options": {
        "userName": "USERNAME",
        "password": "PASSWORD"
      },
      "type": "default"
    },
    "server": "SERVER",
    "options": {
      "validateBulkLoadParameters": false,
      "rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion": true,
      "database": "DATABASE",
      "encrypt": true
    }
  });
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err)
      return callback(err, null);
    const request = new Request(sql, (err, rowCount, rows) => {
      connection.close();
      if (err)
        return callback(err, null);
      callback(null, {rowCount, rows});
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
  });
};
executeSQL("SELECT * FROM users", (err, data) => {
  if (err)
    console.error(err);
  console.log(data.rowCount);
});
//or
executeSQL("SELECT * FROM users", (err, {rowCount, rows}) => {
  if (err)
    console.error(err);
  console.log(rowCount);
});
```