# TransactionError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have the following code snippet

```
await this.repository.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        try {
          await this.repository.deleteData(transaction);
          result = await this.repository.postData(data, transaction);
          await transaction.commit();          
        } catch (e) {
          await transaction.rollback();
          throw (e);
        }
      });
```

In Repository Class I have the following definition of the above function calls

```
 async deleteData(transaction) {
    const result = await this.knex.raw(`
      DELETE Table1
    `)
      .transacting(transaction);

    return result;
  }
  
  
      
        async postData(data, transaction) {
    const query = this.knex.batchInsert('Table1', data, 10)
      .returning('id')
      .transacting(transaction);

    const result = await query;

    return result;
  }
```

I got the following error

```
"TransactionError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Final state"

ConnectionError: Connection lost - write ECONNRESET, "Connection Closed before request completed"
```

running Node 10.21.0,
"knex": "^0.16.3",
"mssql": "^4.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

Issues Connection lost - read ECONNRESET or Connection lost - write ECONNRESET while dealing with large reads or writes using Node.js v10.21+, setting these options in the configuration fixed it for me.

```
encrypt: true,
packetSize: 32768
```

Here is how the Repository class looks like after the above change

```
    import Knex from 'knex';
    
    class Repository {
      constructor(knex) {
        this.knex = knex || Knex({
          client: 'mssql',
          connection: {
      user: '',
      password: '',
      host: '',
      port: '',
      database: '',
      dumpSql: '',
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
        packetSize: 32768,
      },
      requestTimeout: 60000,
    },
        });
      }

  async transaction(args) {
    return this.knex.transaction(args);
  }


     async deleteData(transaction) {
        const result = await this.knex.raw(`
          DELETE Table1
        `)
          .transacting(transaction);
    
        return result;
      }
    
    
    
            async postData(data, transaction) {
        const query = this.knex.batchInsert('Table1', data, 10)
          .returning('id')
          .transacting(transaction);
    
        const result = await query;
    
        return result;
      }
    }
```

REF: https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/923